Rewriting the second derivative of a function by substitution
I would like to know if the equation
$$
\frac{d^2T(x)}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{d}{dT}\left(\frac{d}{dx}T(x)\right)^2\quad(1)
$$
is true for a general function T(x). The function T(x) describes the temperature along a rod, so the function is smooth and its derivatives exist. Working through examples such as $$T(x) = \sin(x)\quad \text{or}\quad T(x) =\sqrt{a+x^2},$$
where it is easy to derive x(T), I can check that (1) is at least true in these cases.
I tried to prove (1) by making the following substitution:
$$
\frac{dT(x)}{dx} = u(x(T)).
$$
Applying the chain-rule to the right hand side of (1) we get:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{d}{dT}\left(u(x(T))\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\cdot2\cdot u(x(T))\cdot\frac{d}{dx}u(x(T))\cdot\frac{d}{dT}x(T).
$$
Canceling the 2's and substituting the original definition back in we get:
$$
u(x(T))\cdot\frac{d}{dx}u(x(T))\cdot\frac{d}{dT}x(T) = \frac{dT(x)}{dx}\cdot\frac{d^2T(x)}{dx^2}\cdot\frac{dx(T)}{dT} =\frac{d^2T(x)}{dx^2},
$$
since
$$
\frac{dT(x)}{dx}= \left(\frac{dx(T)}{dT}\right)^{-1}.
$$
So evidently
$$
\frac{d^2T(x)}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{d}{dT}\left(\frac{dT(x)}{dx}\right)^2.
$$
Physicists (me) have a habit of bending mathematical definitions to suit their needs and to me, defining a function like
$$
\frac{dT(x)}{dx} = u(x(T))
$$
feels wrong, because in a certain sense it is a recursive definition. 
So, is my proof valid? Or, is (1) in general false?

if you just replace $\frac d{dT}$ by $\frac 1{T'(x)} \frac d {dx}$, the proof is very straightforward

Inversion of $(T(\cdot x))$ is assumed with your $u$, apply directly chain rule on right terms of $1$ so finding the left.

Thanks @WW1 & @EDX!
